# Display next combo box based on a value of another combo box in access form

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a combo box with different values to choose from (selection of multiple values are allowed) in the access form. Using MS Access 2016.
I'm trying to write a VBA code that will show next combo box only if the selection contains "*quality*" word and do not show the second combo box if the field is empty or have a different selection.
The original form shouldn't show the second combo box as well.

My current code is:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

If Me.combo1 Like "Quality*" Then
Me.combo2.Visible = True
Else
Me.combo2.Visible = False
End If

End Sub
```

But I'm getting a Run-Time error '13': "Type mismatch" and cannot find what's wrong with the code.

Would be grateful for any help!

Comment: If you are allowing multiple selections in combobox then it must be bound to a multi-value field. Need to understand what a multi-value field really is https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Guide-to-multivalued-fields-7C2FD644-3771-48E4-B6DC-6DE9BEBBEC31. It does not contain CSV text and therefore this code cannot work.

Comment: That's what I was thinking the issue was, thank you! Do you know by any chance any other options to solve this problem?

Comment: Don't use multi-value fields. I NEVER do. Otherwise, code could open a recordset of the multi-value field and examine its content for the data comparison. Or build a saved query object that expands the multi-value field and use DLookup on the query. Sort of guessing because I've never had to deal with issue.

Comment: Thank you @June7

Comment: Could you show the definition of your multi-valued field?

Comment: @LeeMac my selections are Quality Specialist, Quality Other, Quality Admin, NA, IT dpt. Is it possible to somehow access those stored in the background values and check if at least one of the selection contain 'Quality'?

Comment: @Art Could you show the definition (i.e. the properties) of the field itself? e.g. Does it source values from a Value List or Table/Query?

Comment: @LeeMac sorry, the values are sourced from a Value List.